# How do I completely load a pinned youtube tab in background on chrome startup?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Everytime I startup Chrome with Youtube pinned It doesn't load the youtube page completely until I make the tab active - i.e. I click on it. Interestingly tho it's status  according to `chrome.tabs.get()` is 'complete'.

[Here is an example](https://i.imgur.com/R65WxG2.gif)
As you can see, the youtube wasn't loaded until I clicked on it's tab, while stackoverflows website didn't
have to do any loading.

Is there any way I can completely load youtube on chrome startup without explicitly making the tab active i.e. by clicking on it? I tried to execute reload on chrome window startup via `chrome.tabs.reload(pinned_tab_id);`, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Sites can detect their active state so youtube intentionally waits for it. The only solution would be for you to inject a content script that fools the site by spoofing the methods of detection it uses, probably document.visibilityState, document.hasFocus. You'll have to hook these getters in [page context](/a/9517879).